# Is #6 wire suitable for a hot tub circuit?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, hot-tub

I am installing a 60ft run with #4 AWG within 1" EMT from main panel to an exterior subpanel that contains a 60Amp GFCI.  I plan to do a grounding rod at that location, even though it is not required.

My question is, can/should I use 6 AWG from the exterior sub 10 feet to the hot tub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider #4 or #2 aluminum for the feeder.   #4 is 65A and #2 is 90A.  There is nothing wrong with aluminum in heavy feeder; copper is safety theater and wasted safety money.  A few jurisdictions disallow #4 but everyone agrees #2 is fine.

For a 60A load, whether #6 is allowable depends on the cable.

- Copper NM or UF cable must be 4 AWG for 70A.  #6 is only 55A.
- If the terminals on the hot tub are not identified for 75deg C thermal, then you need #4 copper also, since #6 would only be 55A.
- Otherwise, #6 copper works since it is 65A at 75 deg C thermal.
- if the hot tub terminals are labeled for Al wire and 75C, then #4 aluminum is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single type of hot tub, so no absolute answer. But basically it depends on the power requirements.

In a quick search, I found [a chart](http://www.armstrongssupply.com/wire_chart.htm) (but there are plenty of others) that says:

- 55A for cable and 60C termination
- 65A for individual wires and 75C termination
- 75A for individual wires and 90C termination

Since your maximum is 60A, and 90C termination is rare anyway, the question is whether you have 75C termination (i.e., breaker and hot tub equipment). If you do, then you can use 6 AWG and the full 60A. If you don't then you are limited to 55A. So it all depends on the hot tub specifications.